# What is the difference between xspice and x11spice?

Tags: linux, xorg, x-server, spice

Recently I've been trying to enable spice in container using Docker for remote display, I've discovered two applicable resources to do so. First one is the xspice, if I should call it so, which contained in [`xserver-xspice`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/xserver-xspice) package. Second one is [x11spice](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/x11spice). The thing is, I'm not quite sure about the differences between them, can some one kindly explain about them? I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting xserver-xspice project:

> A standalone server that is both an X server and a Spice server. Iow, **you get a new DISPLAY** to launch X clients against, and you can view and interact with them via a spice client.

Conversely, x11spice is:

> x11spice connects a running X server as a Spice server.

So the crucial difference is that with xserver-xspice, you start a new xserver, and inevitably a new session. With x11spice you are getting a spice interface to an already existing xserver and an existing session. For example, there seems to be no way to use xserver-xspice to connect to an existing screen/desktop.